# Connecting balanced output from sound card to unbalanced input of audio amplifier

Tags: amplifier, audio, balanced, unbalanced

I want to connect 4 mono balanced outputs from my [Motu](https://motu.com/en-us/news/introducing-the-ultralite-mk4/) UltraLight mk4 sound card to 4 unbalanced input of a mono audio amplifier [board](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M0FO1JZ)

How should I do that?
Shall I just use unbalanced cable 1/4" TS to 1/4" TS?

Comment: Yes, but TPA3116 has differential inputs so if the board uses these inputs you can connect your balanced outputs directly. If you need 4 channels it would be better to use a 4 channel board (many on aliexpress) because having the 4 amps on the same ground plane has much lower risk of supply/grounding related noise issues.

Comment: Are the balanced outputs also differential?